# Recover my database structure from from files

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

It was my habit to uninstall easyphp without losing my database...But this time, I've uninstalled my easyphp and re-installed it again, but when I tried to view my database, I see that all tables have been lost.

Actually, my tables are all empty, because I've just finished the database conception and I did not yet begun the project online.

But the tables are about 40 table, and I don't want to recreate them again.

so I've viewed my mysql directory, and I see that *.frm files with the names of my tables.

How can I recover my tables structure (not data) from those *.frm files?

Comment: Do you only have the .frm files or do you also have .idb files ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and tried to do this after reading lots of suggestions on the Internet, but the answer is no.

Either find an earlier backup or, as I had to do, redo all your tables.  This is taking me about 2 hours, but I'm going to back up my files a lot more often now :)

Use this as a learning experience.